# How to write interactive program like Top?

Tags: shell, terminal, interactive

When you run the [top](http://www.unixtop.org/), you enter an interactive display that is housed in the terminal, yet the command line is gone.

I want to build a program with this type of display, but don't even know what to research.

- Where do I start?

Comment: ncurses: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Comment: I think you must start checking vt100 control chars for output positioning (ps. yup, ncurses)

Comment: You can look for the ncurses or slang libraries.  They provide the building blocks of for creating this kind of interface.

Comment: I updated my answer to implement the beginning stages of top using the bash shell. You may want to check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`top` used [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) when it was first released, but later switched to its own screen management code because of the overhead associated with *curses*.

More about *top* can be read under the following link:

- http://www.unixtop.org/about.shtml

---

Collectively, what you are looking for falls under the category of [*TUI*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) (Text-based User Interface).

---

Most often [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) is the goto recommendation for someone that wants to incorporate textual representation of "graphics" inside a terminal.

There are however several different alternatives, and I would recommend google for finding a suitable library for you to use. As a start you check out the below listed links:

- [**wikipedia** - Category:Text user interface libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Text_user_interface_libraries)
- [**ncurses FAQ** - How big is it?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#how_big_is_it)
- [**ncurses FAQ** - What other programs are there?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#related_programs)

Answer (score 3):

For educational purposes I propose an imperfect yet usable program which catches arrow keys in bash and responds to them instantly:

```
#!/bin/bash 

# Put terminal into canonical mode with noecho 
# (not required for this example but perhaps useful nonethless )
MYTERMRESTORE=$(stty --save)
stty icanon -echo

# Obtain terminal dimensions 
columns=$(tput cols)
lines=$(tput lines)

# Populate a buffer and store its size
buffer="$(ps aux)"
scroll="${#buffer}"

# Set a top bar and scrolling region (printf "\033[2;${lines}")
tput csr 1 "${lines}"
while [ "${#x}" -lt "$columns" ]
do x="$x="
done
printf "$x\n"

# Set up a continuos loop
while [ 1 ]
do  printf "%.*s"  $scroll  "$buffer"
    printf "\n\nUse arrow keys to toggle through output, q to quit\n"
    read -n 1 i
    case "$i" in
        '[')
             read  -n 1 j
             case "$j" in
                  "A") # Up arrow
                       scroll=$(( scroll - $columns ))
                   ;;
                  "B") # Down arrow
                       scroll=$(( scroll + $columns ))
                   ;;
             esac
             ;;
        'q') break
             ;;
    esac
done


stty "$MYTERMRESTORE"
```

Perhaps the most immediate improvement this program needs is a mechanism to continually update the buffer. In programs with asynchronous multiplexing user input this is often accomplished using `select()`.